# "Satz vom Grunde" - wie soll ich das verstehen

Tags: meaning

Im "Die Welt als Wille und Vorstellung" Schopenhauers lese ich

> (...) denn alle diese [Zeit, Raum und Kasualität] setzen jene eben schon voraus, und wenn jede dieser Formen, welche alle wir als so viele besondere Gestaltungen des **Satzes vom Grunde** erkannt haben (...)

Wie soll ich aber diesen *Satz vom Grunde* verstehen? Das finde ich sehr rätselhaft...

Answer (score 1):

Konzentriert auf einen Satz ist dieser Satz, dass nichts passiert ohne Grund, oder: *Keine Sache ohne Ursache.*

Eine ausführliche Erörterung findet sich, wie so oft, auf [Wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Satz_vom_zureichenden_Grund).